# Check what master page a file is being included in

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm including a file "header.inc" in to several different master pages. Is there a way for me to tell which master page is calling header.inc from within that file?

The code is something like this:

MasterPage.master:

```
...
<!-- #Include virtual="/partials/header.inc" -->
...
```

header.inc:

```
...
<%
If (MasterPageFileName === "MasterPage") Then
    'Do Something
End If
%>
...
```

I inherited this legacy project from one of my predecessors, so I'm new to ASP; I typically work with PHP.

Comment: if you are using includes, you are thinking about asp.net in the wrong way. as masterpage itself is a way to "include" that content on all pages. check out masterpage functionality: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx. Also look at how to programmatically access master page content from the child page. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx

Comment: Will check out that documentation, thanks. The reason I'm including this stuff is I have ~15 different MasterPage templates, and the majority of this section stays the same for every one of these pages.

Comment: So nest your master pages? Or create a reusable control you can place on the master pages?

Comment: Is this an actual ASP.NET "MasterPage" page? SSI-style includes don't work in ASP.NET. Is this a Classic ASP site instead?

Comment: @Dai honeslty I'm not sure, from what I understand this is ASP.NET, and the server side includes seem to be working. The file names where I'm including things all end in .master.

Comment: @JacobTheDev you can tell easily enough, if the file extensions are .asp then it's classic ASP, if they're .aspx then it's ASP.NET

Comment: @ADyson, yeah they're .aspx.

Comment: @mason, I don't fully understand that, but I'll look in to it, thanks.